# Suggestions on how to upgrade HTML and CSS making a hamburger icon that transitions to "X" in the code below?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

I'm interested in how I can improve my HTML and CSS? I didn't yet learn JS, even though I used it for onclick function, so I'm not currently interested in how to improve the JS in this code. I was wondering:

Is it alright to use spans inside button for accessibility? First I had all divs, than made the parent div into a button tag so that the HTML is more accessible. Then I read that divs shouldn't be in button tags so I switched them for spans. Also input tag with checkbox is less informative probably?

Is it OK to use span tags instead of ::before and ::after? I was first trying with pseudoelements but they didn't work with flex and alignments somehow, so I used spans, and later didin't try with pseudoelements. Is there any benefit to writing pseudo as opposed to two additional spans?

Could I use flex and then style the transitions? I found that it was really hard to get the right dimensions when using flex, so I switched to position: absolute and insets. What is best practice when also doing transitions and having to calculate stuff?

I also don't understand why the effect after deleting this part of the code causes misalignment as I thought it should only cause the span "lines" to be "longer":

.burger-top-open, .burger-bot-open { width: 50%; }

LINK: https://jsitor.com/kAkUItFAM

```js
function myFunction() {
  var burgerTop = document.getElementsByClassName("burger-top");
  burgerTop[0].classList.toggle("burger-top-open");

  var burgerMid = document.getElementsByClassName("burger-mid");
  burgerMid[0].classList.toggle("burger-mid-open");

  var burgerBot = document.getElementsByClassName("burger-bot");
  burgerBot[0].classList.toggle("burger-bot-open");
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.burger-box {
  all: unset;
  height: clamp(2rem, 20vw, 10rem);
  width: clamp(2rem, 20vw, 10rem);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}

.burger {
  position: absolute;
  height: 15%;
  width: 55%;
  background-color: darkblue;
  border-radius: 15rem;
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}

.burger-top {
  top: calc(25% - 6.25%);
  left: 0
}

.burger-mid {
  top: calc(50% - 6.25%);
  width: 100%;
}

.burger-bot {
  top: calc(75% - 6.25%);
  right: 0
}

.burger-top-open,
.burger-bot-open {
  width: 50%;
}

.burger-mid-open {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.burger-top-open {
  transform: rotate(-315deg) translateX(25%) translateX(-6.25%);
}

.burger-bot-open {
  transform: rotate(-315deg) translateX(-25%) translateX(6.25%);
}
```

```html
<article>
  <button class="burger-box" onclick="myFunction()">
    <span class="burger burger-top"></span>
    <span class="burger burger-mid"></span>
    <span class="burger burger-bot"></span>
  </button>
</article>
```

Comment: We require that the code be working correctly, to the best of the author's knowledge, before proceeding with a review. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @BCdotWEB I don't know what you mean, it does work correctly?

Comment: I misread the `I also don't understand why the effect after deleting this part of the code causes misalignment as I thought it should only cause the span "lines" to be "longer":`. Still, that part is off-topic here.